# Javascript Regex validator for specific condition

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a javascript regex validator which can full fill the following condition.

1. String should contain alphabets and space only.
2. First character must be alphabetic (Lowercase or uppercase).
3. Space is allowed but not mandatory.
4. Space should not be repeated. But there can be multiple space in string.
5. Last character must be alphabetic (Lowercase or uppercase).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: trivial regex. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried - "/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]+[a-zA-Z]$/". But its not working @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
var re = /^(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/

re.test('a')     // true
re.test('ab')    // true
re.test('a b')   // true
re.test('a b c') // true
re.test('a  b')  // false
re.test('ab ')   // false
re.test(' ab')   // false
re.test('ab1')   // false
```

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking: `/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s?)*[a-zA-Z]$/.test("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8")`. Use `/^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$/` instead

Comment: @nhahtdh Good catch. It does remind me to consider my answer again. Removed the unnecessary pitfall `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the existing answers have catastrophic backtracking problem, or way too convoluted, here is a simpler solution:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$/.test(input)
```

I changes `\s` to a simple space, since `\s` matches space, tab, newline, among other characters.

### Appendix

[Leo's answer at revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30565864/2) has catastrophic backtracking problem:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s?)*[a-zA-Z]$/
```

You can try with a simple failing string. For example:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s?)*[a-zA-Z]$/.test("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8")
```

The problem is due to the optional `\s`, which causes the `(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s?)*` to degenerate to `(?:[a-zA-Z]+)*`, which is the classical catastrophic backtracking pattern `(A*)*`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. From a performance perspective, is there difference between my current answer and yours (except for the `\s` thing, I leave the decision to OP)? There're other approaches, like `/^(?:[a-z]+\s)*[a-z]+$/i`, I think it'll be a little slower, does it?

Comment: @Leo: `token (sep token)*` form incurs less backtracking than `(token sep)* token` in matching case. For the last `token`, it always goes into `(token sep)`, match `token` but can't match `sep`, then it has to backtrack and rematch `token`, so it's slower (but it's nowhere as significant as catastrophic backtracking, and probably not observable in most cases). I still recommend using `token (sep token)*`, though, since it's a probable gain without any loss in clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*[a-zA-Z]+)+/i; 
var str = 'sample test';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

for understanding or to modify [check out playground here](https://regex101.com/r/qD9nQ8/1)

Comment: `re.test('ab ') // true`, fail

Comment: The regex is convoluted, and the solution is more complex that it should be.

Comment: I am also new to regex, it looked understandable for me. 
is anything wrong in the solution?

Comment: @SunilBN: The regex is in poor form. It doesn't cause catastrophic backtracking as it is, but a small addition of `$` at the end will cause the problem - so just don't show code like this. See my answer for the simpler solution. Another thing is that OP wants to validate the whole string, not just matching the string.